# Using percentages to apply Fisher's exact test

Tags: statistics, independence

I have a $2\times2$ contingency table, but the total sample size is too large to be able to directly apply Fisher's exact test (as it involves factorials, so I'll obtain NaN or infinity). Data are like that:

```
       A=1     A=0
 B=1   10000   6900
 B=0   89333   120033
```

I know I could use chi.square instead, but I wanted to provide Fisher's exact test results. Among other reasons, because calculating left and right p-values of Fisher's exact test I can have the probabilities of positive or negative associations between variables.

Could it be appropiate and acceptable to firstly transform the contingency table in percentajes, so sample size=100, then apply Fisher's exact test?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: As the counts become large Fisher's exact test becomes a Chi-Squared test.

Comment: No. Results would not be accurate. If you could give the exact data causing the difficulty, we might be able to be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added more info to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as BruceET commented, using percentages in turn of real data to apply Fisher's test does not seem accurate.
In turn I think I found a possible solution to be able to calculate Fisher's test even for large numbers, using gammaln function. In this way, I can work with the logarithm of factorials in turn of factorials themselves. This makes quite easier to calculate Fisher's test even for large numbers.
Hope this can help!

Comment: This might work computationally. but it's not illuminating as to what actually happens for large numbers which make asymptotics easy:
$$\binom n {an}\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi a(1-a)n}}(a^a(1-a)^{1-a})^{-n}=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi a(1-a)n}}2^{nH_2(a)}$$
and is a great approximation when $n$ is large. Simply plug this into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test#Example for all $3$ binomials and actually see what happens depending on specific ratios.